# C# FileSystemEventHander won't Trigger from FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I've tried about 100 variations of this code using MS and SO as references and I cannot get the file to trigger.  Actually, that's not entirely accurate.  I got it the first time, but only the first time.

It's a simple FileSystemWatcher, I'm looking for files being created (either created directly via another process, or files that were copied.

Here is my code, what am I missing?

```
public Form_Status() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Show();

        this.lblStatusText.Text = "Creating Jobs";
        Watch(@"\\erpsql\p21shares\PurchasingSave");

    }

    private static void Watch(string path) {

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()) {
            watcher.Path = path;

            // LastWrite Triggers
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        // Do Something
        MessageBox.Show("Created Job: {0}", e.Name);
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
    }
```

Comment: This might be a little stupid - but aren't you disposing of the watcher with `using` statement? I have no knowledge on FileSystemWatcher, so I might be wrong though.

Comment: @GrayCat is correct, the watcher will be immediately disposed. You need to store it in an instance variable, or set a timer/waithandle/loop inside your using statement. Note: If you store it in an instance variable, you should dispose of it later manually

Comment: If this is WinForms, just add the `FileSystemWatcher` using the designer and don't worry about disposing of it; that'll be taken care of when your form closes.

Comment: When you have removed that `using` statement (dispose of the FSW in the `Form.FormClosed` event or when you're done with it), add `NotifyFilters.FileName`. You'll have it working as intended. Note that the `Changed` event will be raised twice.

Comment: Give the `Created` event it's own handler.